# Sequelize generate models from existing tables over ssh

Tags: node.js, ssh, sequelize.js

I'm trying to generate models in my node project for existing db and I'm using `Sequlize` ORM.
The documentation says you can generate with the following command

```
sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models] -t [tableName]
```

My problem is I can connect to my db server only over ssh using public/private key pair.
I looked into the `sequelize-auto` options and couldn't find an option for ssh connection.
How can I generate the models for the remote db over ssh?

Answer (score 0):

The password in that command is for the database, not for the ssh connection. Your application server would also need to connect to the database without ssh.

Comment: So as I understand there is no way with ssh, right?
All our servers are accessible only over ssh, it means I won't be able to generate it

Comment: Ask your admin if the database is available over the public internet or only internally.